# Версионирование API Spring

Tags: java, spring, api, версионирование

У меня есть старый контроллер, который обслуживает все запросы по адресу `/get`, то есть на уровне класса стоит аннотация `@RequestMapping(value = "get")`.

Однако, появилась необходимость разработать новое API, не внося изменений в старое. 
Новое API должно обрабатывать запросы по адресу `/get/v2`. Это будет совершенно новый класс со своими обработчиками.

Как сделать так, чтобы запросы, которые начинаются с `/get/v2` попадали в новый контроллер, а не старый?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что ничего специально предпринимать не нужно, и Spring совершенно автоматически и корректно назначает обработчики, если нет очевидных коллизий.